# Bootstrap multiselect: clicking on dropdown disables all input and button elements on panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am extending a web page that lets users select a type (corresponding to a reference table like Division, Department, Locations, etc.), so the existing code generates the HTML that renders a table of the selected type's records for editing: textboxes for name, description, single-select dropdown for Status, Update button.
The new type requires a multi-select dropdown, with the current values selected. The bootstrap multiselect gets rendered just fine--I see the current values on the records that have them, and "None selected" for the others. When I click on the dropdown, it, along with every other input/select/button on the Bootstrap panel, gets disabled.

Here's the css:

```html
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Datatables/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Datatables/fixedHeader.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Datatables/responsive.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Datatables/select.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's the script:

```html
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect-collapsible-groups.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.fixedHeader.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.select.js"></script>
```

Here's where I'm generating the HTML table with the records to update:

```js
var siteRoot = '@Url.Content("~/")';

/* functionality and field are selected from dropdowns on the page; they identify which type (i.e. reference table) to update.
field 'baseline' is the one that needs a multiselect.
*/
var populateTable = function (functionality, field) {
    $("#dataGridPanel table tbody").html("");
    getDataValues(functionality, field)
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                createTableForFieldType($("#dataGridPanel table"), functionality, field, data);
            }
        });
}
    
var getDataValues = function (functionality, fieldName) {
    return $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: siteRoot + "DataManagement/GetEntityValues",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "functionality": functionality,
            "fieldName": fieldName
        })
    });
};

var createTableForFieldType = function (table, functionality, fieldName, rowData) {
    table = $(table);
    table.html("");
    table.append($(document.createElement("thead")).append(createTableHeaderRow(fieldName)));
    table.append($(document.createElement("tbody")));

    switch (fieldName) {
        case "baseline":
            getDataValues(functionality, "operatingsystem").success(function (dependencyData) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
                    $("tbody", table).append(createTableUpdateRow(functionality, fieldName, rowData[i]));
                }
                /* load all Baseline OS dropdowns with all OS values */
                var dropdowns = $("select.operatingsystem");

                for (var i = 0; i < dependencyData.length; i++) {
                    var option = $(document.createElement("option")).val(dependencyData[i].Id).text(dependencyData[i].Name);
                    dropdowns.append(option);
                }

                dropdowns.each(function () {
                    $(this).multiselect();
                });

                /* select the current value(s), stored in an attribute of each select as a comma-separated string of OSIds, in createTableUpdateRow */
                dropdowns.each(function () {
                    var OSIds = $(this).attr("osids");
                    if (OSIds.length > 0)
                    {
                        var OSIdArray = OSIds.split(",");
                        $(this).multiselect("select", OSIdArray);
                    }
                    $(this).multiselect("refresh");
                });
            });
            break;
        default:
            table.append(createTableAddRow(fieldName));
            for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
                $("tbody", table).append(createTableUpdateRow(functionality, fieldName, rowData[k]));
            }
            break;
    }
};
```

The createTableUpdateRow function with irrelevant code removed (the multiselect dropdown is a list of operating system ids/names):

```js
var createTableHeaderRow = function (fieldName) {
    var row = $(document.createElement("tr"));
    var headerNames = [];

    switch (fieldName) {
        case "baseline":
            headerNames = ["Name", "Status", "Description", "SourceId", "OS", "Last Modified By", "Last Modified Date"];
            break;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < headerNames.length; i++) {
        row.append($(document.createElement("td")).text(headerNames[i]));
    }

    return row;
};

var createTableUpdateRow = function (functionality, fieldName, rowData) {
    var row = $(document.createElement("tr")).attr("data-forid", rowData.Id || rowData.UniqueId);
    var cellContents = [];

    var lastModifiedDate = rowData.LastModifiedDate == null ? null : new Date(parseInt(rowData.LastModifiedDate.substr(6)));
    var dateFormatted = (lastModifiedDate != null ? lastModifiedDate.toDateString() : "");

    var statusSelect = "<select class=\"form-control status\">" +
        "<option value=\"\"" + (rowData.Status == null ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") + ">--Select a Status--</option>" +
        "<option value=\"1\"" + (rowData.Status === 1 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") + ">Active</option>" +
        "<option value=\"0\"" + (rowData.Status === 0 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") + ">Inactive</option>" +
        "</select>";

    var dependentSelect = $(document.createElement("select")).addClass("form-control");

    switch (fieldName) {
        case "baseline":
            /* attr("osids") has the current comma-separated OSId values */
            var multiSelect = $(document.createElement("select")).addClass("operatingsystem").attr("multiple", "multiple").attr("osids", rowData.OSIds == null ? "" : rowData.OSIds);
            /* multiSelect.append("<option value=\"\"" + (rowData.Id == null ? " selected=\"selected\"" : "") + ">--Select an OS--</option>"); */
            cellContents = [
                rowData.Name,
                statusSelect,
                rowData.Description,
                rowData.SourceId,
                multiSelect,
                rowData.LastModifiedByUserId,
                dateFormatted,
                $(document.createElement("button")).attr("data-action", "update").attr("data-forid", rowData.Id).attr("type", "button").addClass("btn btn-primary").html("Update")
            ];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < cellContents.length; i++) {
        row.append($(document.createElement("td")).append(cellContents[i]));
    }

    return row;
};
```

Comment: "Here's the css:" shows the same `<script>` tags as "Here's the script:". Why put code in runnable snippets yet not bother to define `getDataValues` etc.? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the getDataValues function. It's been years since I posted to SO; hey, it's tough to strike a balance between completeness and conciseness ; )

Comment: Still not runnable since `siteRoot` and `functionality` aren't defined. An example that isn't complete can't be concise. "It's been years since I posted to SO" → that's what the link I posted is for.

Comment: I think I've included ALL the relevant code. I'm sure you'll let me know if I'm still missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Try clicking "Run code snippet".

Comment: I added the missing code. Still working on the relevant/complete principle (I'll get it soon). The Run Code Snippets are clean now.

Comment: Resolved it. Elsewhere in the code (this is a web site I recently inherited), an on-click event for all button elements in the panel was checking for a data value. The buttons in question were Add and Update buttons (i.e. data values 'add' or 'update'). Introducing the multiselect added another button element. I added some code to make this event handler ignore the multiselect button, and all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. Elsewhere in the code, an on-click event for all button elements in the panel was checking for a data value. The buttons in question were Add and Update buttons (i.e. data values 'add' or 'update'). Introducing the multiselect added another button element. I added some code to make this event handler ignore the multiselect button, and all is good now.